# android simple server-client implementatiom

Tags: android, client

I am new to android development, and would like to do an application that pulls data from a server, is there any straight-forward and to the point tutorial that I can use?

Comment: you can search for json parsing , xml parsing tutorial in android there are a lot of them available or go for www.vogella.de its a good one with a full android tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to pick data from server then you convert the inputs trim to string then you can parse for further use.`

```
public static InputStream getUrlData(final String url)
        throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    final HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return res.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

its easy to do that with Andorid, just use a rest service and you are on your way

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

http://timewasted.net/?p=127

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefaultHttpClient for this approach.

Take a look at this

[Check out this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)